# Document tags in vectorization models

Tags: python, vectorization, word2vec, doc2vec, fasttext

I am a little new to python and the unsupervised learning methods, but I have a quick question. where as doc2vec model has docvecs property holding all trained vectors for the 'document tags' seen during training; Are there similar properties that holds trained vectors for models like glove, word2vec, fastext, tfidf and some related text vectorsiation models in python, what do could they be?
For example doc2vec model could look like this when extracting vectors for classification

```
doc2vecModel.docvecs['Text_'+str(i)]
```

Comment: This is somewhat too generic to answer, except to say, yes, there are always ways to lookup the vectors – and it depends on the exact libraries/classes you're using (which you don't mention), so you should follow the docs/tutorials for those exact libraries/classes.

Comment: Models like word2vec, fastext and doc2vec are gensim models which are kind of not clear on that. With the glove, I am trying to follow this tutorial [http://www.foldl.me/2014/glove-python/ ]